# What does Method = "put document: 12.0.0.4518" means?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I was trying to upload large size file on Sharepoint.
And got following [code sample](http://vspug.com/smc750/2009/05/19/uploading-content-into-sharepoint-let-me-count-the-ways/) (i.e FrontPage RPC (Remote Procedure Calls))

I am not getting use of "put document: 12.0.0.4518" and

"string serviceName = "http://servername/sitename/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll";".

I have worked on code but it is showing " Response time Out" error.
But since i can't understand the code.It is not possible for me to solve this or any future problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Sharepoint Version.

Check Following Link:
http://mindsharpblogs.com/penny/articles/481.aspx